# undefined instead of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css, dom

`element.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].innerHTML` is fine but not
`element.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(":nth-child(3)").innerHTML` (outputs `undefined`)

I also tried different numbers in `:nth-child()` but without any progress.

Any ideas why?

I get this with Mozilla Firefox 91.0.

Comment: How `element.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].innerHTML` isn't a working code for me? What?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live)
> NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the
> specified group of selectors.

For this reason it returns you a list of nodes from the DOM, basically you can think of an array of elements which matches all of the CSS selector, so you will have to choose one of them and then call the `innerHTML` on it.

Something like this:

```
el.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(":nth-child(3)")[0].innerHTML
```

The example below demonstrates it for you

```js
var el = document.getElementById("span1")
//document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (el.parentNode.parentNode.children[3].innerHTML);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (el.parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll(":nth-child(3)")[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
    <span id="span1"> 1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
   <span id="span2"> 2</span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <span id="span3"> 3</span>
    </div>
     <div>
    <span id="span4"> 4</span>
    </div>

</div>

<hr/>
<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: While this is a good answer, the question is off-topic for the Code Review Community so I doubt you will get many up votes.

Comment: Thanks @pacmaninbw I understand but I was also trying to be helpful which I think is the primary spirit of the whole community :)